# Best way to handle these events in Java/JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, instance-variables

I am not sure if this is proper or not but I wanted to keep my code clean and decided to create different Classes for handling different events. Up until now, I was only handling static variables. Now I was trying to handle instance variables in the same way but not sure if I can do this.

Is there a way to pass the Rectangle object to my EventHandler or should I simply use Lambda for this case ?

> **MainClass.java**

```
//Static example
static TextField acTxt = new TextField();
...

acTxt.setText("Aircraft Number");
acTxt.setOnMouseReleased(new ClickAction());

...

//Instance Variable Example
public void printRec(){
    for(int i = 0; i < acArray.get(j).flight_array.size(); i++){
        Rectangle leg_rec = new Rectangle(i*10,i*10,10,15);
        leg_rec.setOnMouseClicked(new ClickAction());
    }
}

...
```

> **ClickAction.java Class**

```
import static MainClass.acTxt;

    public class ClickAction implements EventHandler<Event>{

        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            if(event.getSource().equals(acTxt)){
                acTxt.clear();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't ever make things static simply to provide access to them. By making a field static you completely change its scope. With the exception of constant fields, static fields are almost always a bad design choice and if you are just beginning with Java my advice is to avoid using static for anything except the `main` method and genuine constants.

> should I simply use [a] Lambda [expression]

Why wouldn't you? Just do

```
acTxt.setOnMouseReleased(e -> acTxt.clear());
```

This is less verbose, easier to read and understand (assuming you are familiar with lambda expressions, which doesn't take much practice). The actual behavior is defined right where the control is defined, so you don't have to go digging in a different class to discover what happens when the mouse is released.

> Is there a way to pass the `Rectangle` object to my `EventHandler`

I assume you mean the `TextField` here...? Yes, of course: if you really want to define the event handler as a stand-alone class, just do as you suggest and pass the text field to it....

```
public class ClickAction implements EventHandler<Event>{

    private final TextField textField ;

    public ClickAction(TextField textField) {
        this.textField = textField ;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Event event) {
        textField.clear();
    }

}
```

and then

```
acTxt.setText("Aircraft Number");
Rectangle leg_rect = ... ;
leg_rect.setOnMouseReleased(new ClickAction(acTxt));
```

Comment: I was asking about the Rectangle Object since I thought I was already handling my TextField correctly but I imagine it will be the same with the Rectangle. The reason I thought different classes would be better is because I have many buttons and fields and I thought it would be better to keep the logic for what is actually happening with the code separate to all the event handling that is simply calling different methods back in my "logic" class.

Comment: But why would you want to pass the `Rectangle` to the handler? The handler clears a text field, so it just needs a reference to the text field. You could obviously pass a reference to the rectangle, but it's not clear you need one.

Comment: In my Handler I clear the field if the source is the acTxt field and I translate  the Rectangle if the the source is the Rectangle

Comment: This is my full code if you are curious. I still need to clean it https://github.com/neilnm/AiManager/ and what I am trying to implement now is to translate the Rectangles when I press the LEFT or RIGHT key.

Comment: Those are two completely different actions, so there is no sense is using the same handler class for them. Use different handlers, whether you implement them with two different stand-alone classes or with lambda expressions.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am using a different Class for the Key event. The textfield and its handler class was just an example for the static case. You already answered my main question which was if I could pass the object to the handler class, this leg_rect.setOnMouseReleased(new ClickAction(acTxt)); is what I was missing. So is it always preferred to use Lambda even if you have multiple buttons/texfields etc... ? I thought it would be cleaner to to have separate classes to handle all the different events. Might end up with too many classes as well.

Comment: "Preferred" is purely subjective. Personally, *I* prefer lambdas (which maybe just call a private method elsewhere in the class, call a method via some existing reference) to explicitly creating additional classes, except for the (extremely rare) situation where a single handler might be reused across multiple parts of the application (i.e. from different controllers entirely).

Comment: To be clear, what I meant by "Preferred" is what is the industry Best Practice or the norm for this or is there none and its a matter of "Preference" ?

Comment: It's definitely a style preference, not a matter of industry best practice. Your company likely has coding style practice recommendations for this.